# Using nodemailer to send email from app upon click of element

Tags: jquery, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to incorporate nodemailer into my app and want it to send emails upon submission of a contact form. I managed to get the basic functionality of nodemailer working with the following in my app.js file:

```
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '********', //email address to send from
            pass: '*********' //the actual password for that account
        }
    });

var mailOptions = {
from: 'Dave <***********>',
to: '*************',
subject: 'Nodemailer test',
text: 'You have reported this comment'
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err,res){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log('Email sent');
}
})
```

This sends emails successfully on app startup so I've got the functionality working. However, how do I then incorporate this into my app? For example, if I have a button:

```
  <button id="report">Submit</button>
```

How do I get an email to send upon click of this button? Tried using just jQuery with something like:

```
$('#report').on('click', function(){
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err,res){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log('Email sent');
}
})
})
```

But obviously didn't work.

Comment: Bump!!!! I want to learn the answer!